# Multiple line processing by SED to change incoming e-mail sender and keep their e-mail within bugzilla comments

Tags: email, sed, smtp, bugzilla, procmail

I am using Bugzilla also to process publicly reported bugs. But I do not want to create account for anybody who may send a bug report.
It is easily done by changing the From SMTP header. But of course I would like to keep the Sender e-mail to be visible somewhere within the bug.

I am struggling with how to make sed to put the line as the first line of the plain/text part of the e-mail.
The issue boils down to how to put a specific line after the first empty line after a block of lines where is a line compliant to REGEXP
    `/\(Content-Type: text\/plain.*\)/`

Currently, I am able to put it after 
    `Content-Type: text/plain`
line, which is always present.
The problem is that sometimes it is not the last line of the SMTP header.
    `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable`
or other header may follow.
(It is enough to take care of the text/plain part which is either alone or comes in pair with text/html part, which does not have to be processed since bugzilla accept it only as an attachment anyway.)

So far, I am using .procmailrc to preprocess the incoming e-mails:

```
LOGFILE=/home/bugmail/procmail.log


## Mails from myserver.com goes to bugzilla as-is
:0
* ^To:.*@otherservice.com.*
* ^From:.*@myserver.com.*
|/var/www/www.alfa.myserver.com/bugzilla/email_in.pl -vvv --default op_sys=All --override product="app-support" --default rep_platform=All --override component="Startovac" --default version=unspecified


## Mails from myserver.com goes to bugzilla as-is
:0
* ^From:.*@myserver.com.*
|/var/www/www.alfa.myserver.com/bugzilla/email_in.pl -vvv --default op_sys=All --override product="app-support" --default rep_platform=All --override component="Default" --default version=unspecified


## Mails from external address that is multipart/*
:0
* ^To:.*@otherservice.com.*
* Content-Type: multipart/*
| sed -n 's/\(Content-Type: text\/plain.*\)/\1\n\nFromNew: app-support@myserver.com/; p' | sed '/^From:\(.*@.*\)/{h; s//FromNew: app-support@myserver.com/;b};/FromNew: app-support@myserver.com/x' | sed -e '1,/^From:/s/^From:/FromOriginal:/' | sed -e '1,/^FromNew:/s/^FromNew:/From:/' |/var/www/www.alfa.myserver.com/bugzilla/email_in.pl -vvv --default op_sys=All --override product="app-support" --default rep_platform=All --override component="Specificcomponent" --default version=unspecified


## Mails from external address that is multipart/*
:0
* Content-Type: multipart/*
| sed -n 's/\(Content-Type: text\/plain.*\)/\1\n\nFromNew: app-support@myserver.com/; p' | sed '/^From:\(.*@.*\)/{h; s//FromNew: app-support@myserver.com/;b};/FromNew: app-support@myserver.com/x' | sed -e '1,/^From:/s/^From:/FromOriginal:/' | sed -e '1,/^FromNew:/s/^FromNew:/From:/' |/var/www/www.alfa.myserver.com/bugzilla/email_in.pl -vvv --default op_sys=All --override product="app-support" --default rep_platform=All --override component="Default" --default version=unspecified

## Mails from external address that is only text/plain
:0
* ^To:.*@myserver.com.*
|sed -e '1,/^$/s/^$/\nFromNew: app-support@myserver.com/' | sed '/^From:\(.*@.*\)/{h; s//FromNew: app-support@myserver.com/;b};/FromNew: app-support@myserver.com/x' | sed -e '1,/^From:/s/^From:/FromOriginal:/' | sed -e '1,/^FromNew:/s/^FromNew:/From:/' |/var/www/www.alfa.myserver.com/bugzilla/email_in.pl -vvv --default op_sys=All --override product="app-support" --default rep_platform=All --override component="Default" --default version=unspecified

## Mails from external address that is only text/plain
:0
* ^To:.*@otherservice.com.*
|sed -e '1,/^$/s/^$/\nFromNew: app-support@myserver.com/' | sed '/^From:\(.*@.*\)/{h; s//FromNew: app-support@myserver.com/;b};/FromNew: app-support@myserver.com/x' | sed -e '1,/^From:/s/^From:/FromOriginal:/' | sed -e '1,/^FromNew:/s/^FromNew:/From:/' |/var/www/www.alfa.myserver.com/bugzilla/email_in.pl -vvv --default op_sys=All --override product="app-support" --default rep_platform=All --override component="Specificcomponent" --default version=unspecified
```

So if the Sender does not come from myserver.com , the From is set as app-support@myserver.com (which is an existing Bugzilla user) and the original From e-mail is moved to the first line of the e-mail body.

The problem arises when the 
    `Content-Type: text/plain`
header is followed by other headers. The text is then put into Bugzilla comment as

```
>> Pokou=C5=A1el jsem se vlo=C5=BEit obr=C3=A1zek pomoc=C3=AD tla=C4=8D=C3=
```

which is not very readable.

Maybe `SED` is not the right tool but I would like to keep the preprocessing as a one-liner in .procmailrc to keep it in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` to parse MIME messages is going to be challenging, to say the least.  Since you are already apparently using Perl for other things, I would implement this logic in a simple Perl script as well.  Adding decoding for the various MIME content-transfer-encodings is then a trivial addition.

Perl's [Email::MIME package](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-MIME-1.911/lib/Email/MIME.pm) might be a good starting point.  You already seem to have a basic understanding of the problem domain; many beginners would make the mistake of assuming that all messages are multiparts, or that all messages have exactly one `text/plain` part. (Maybe still emphasize that there may be none!  Some clients just send a binary `application/octet-stream` if there is no textual content, or the client may be set up to only compose `text/html` and not generate a `text/plain` rendering for those of us who prefer that.)